# How to pass a value to shell script from subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I have the following:

**myscript.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from threading import Thread
import time
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("./hello.sh 1", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("./hello.sh 2", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("./hello.sh 3", shell=True)
```

**hello.sh**

```
echo "Hello From Shell Script $1"
```

**The output is:**

```
Hello From Shell Script 1
Hello From Shell Script 2
Hello From Shell Script 3
```

I want to do this in a for loop like so:

```
for num in range(1,3):
    subprocess.Popen(['./hello.sh', str(num)], shell=True)
```

But the output is:

```
Hello From Shell Script
Hello From Shell Script
Hello From Shell Script
```

If I drop the **shell=True** so its now:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./hello.sh', str(num)])
```

I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 12, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(['./hello.sh', str(num)])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 623, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1141, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

How can I get this to pass in the correct value to the script?

Comment: Since you are passing list of arguments, simply drop `shell=True` keyword argument.

Comment: See my edit @Rogalski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to read as follows:

```
>>> for num in range(1,3):
...     subprocess.Popen(['./hello.sh '+str(num)], shell=True)
```

Comment: There's no reason to pass a list to `Popen` if it only contains one string.

Comment: @chepner Is it a list?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `shell=True` if you are passing a list instead of a string as the first argument.

```
subprocess.Popen(['./hello.sh', str(num)])
```

Comment: Isn't `shell=True` required for "./hello.sh"?

Comment: Not necessarily. If the script is executable, `execve` will execute the script with `/bin/sh` (or whatever its shebang specifies). Specifying `shell=True` is just a shortcut for `["/bin/sh", "-c"] + arglist`. (Where `arglist` is either the list you pass, or a single-element list containing the string you passed.)

Comment: I'd say just "Don't use `shell=True`". Period.